# Received error while trying to add font for Snake Game (C Language)

Tags: c

So i am trying to add a font into my program (which is located in the same folder with the program) to display my score and the words for the Game Over screen. But it seems that it is not working. I tried to google for solutions, and all i got is people saying that the font location is wrong / try another font. For the first one, i am confirm the font location is correct and for the second, it does not work also. Is there any way to solve this problem? [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gDwyS.jpg)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#define SDL_MAIN_HANDLED
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL_ttf.h>
#include <time.h>

//use const int so that the value cannot be changed.
const int WINDOW_WIDTH = 640;
const int WINDOW_HEIGHT = 480;
const int GRID_SIZE = 20;
const int GAME_SPEED = 150;

//array set to 100, indicate the maximu length for the snake is 100 only.
int snakeX[100], snakeY[100];
// Assigning variables.
int snakeLength;
int fruitX, fruitY;
int score;
int direction;
int gameOver;
TTF_Font* font = NULL;

//game window create by SDL
SDL_Window* window = NULL;
//this pointer indicates the rendere associated with the game window.
SDL_Renderer* renderer = NULL;

//error checking
bool init() {
    //Obtaining the error by using the SDL_GetError()
    //Check if SDL initialization with video support was succesful. If there is error then print message. 
    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) < 0) {
        printf("SDL could not initialize! SDL_Error: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
        return false;
    }
    
    //This will create a window with the words Snake Game, but if failed will print the error message.
    window = SDL_CreateWindow("Snake Game", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
    if (window == NULL) {
        printf("Window could not be created! SDL_Error: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
        return false;
    }

    //Will create renderer that associates with the game window, but if failed will print the error message.
    renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED);
    if (renderer == NULL) {
        printf("Renderer could not be created! SDL_Error: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
        return false;
    }

    //load the font into the program
    TTF_Font* font = TTF_OpenFont("arial.ttf",24);
    //print message if there is any error
    if(font == NULL){
        printf("Failed to load the font!: %s\n",TTF_GetError());
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

//cleaning up and close the SDL resources when game finished. It destroys the renderer and windwow after that quit the program. 
void close() {
    SDL_DestroyRenderer(renderer);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    SDL_Quit();
    TTF_Quit();
}

//capture the keyboard input
void handleInput() {
    SDL_Event event;
    while (SDL_PollEvent(&event)) {
        //check any quitting game event, for example closing window, if yes then game over.
        if (event.type == SDL_QUIT) {
            gameOver = true;
        }
        //check which key has been input.
        else if (event.type == SDL_KEYDOWN) {
            switch (event.key.keysym.sym) {
                case SDLK_UP:
                case SDLK_w:
                    if (direction != 2)
                        direction = 0;
                    break;

                case SDLK_DOWN:
                case SDLK_s:
                    if (direction != 0)
                        direction = 2;
                    break;

                case SDLK_LEFT:
                case SDLK_a:
                    if (direction != 1)
                        direction = 3;
                    break;

                case SDLK_RIGHT:
                case SDLK_d:
                    if (direction != 3)
                        direction = 1;
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}

//generate the fruit position randomly
void generateFruit() {
    fruitX = rand() % (WINDOW_WIDTH / GRID_SIZE);
    fruitY = rand() % (WINDOW_HEIGHT / GRID_SIZE);
}


//move the snake
void moveSnake() {
    for (int i = snakeLength; i > 0; --i) {
        snakeX[i] = snakeX[i - 1];
        snakeY[i] = snakeY[i - 1];
    }

    switch (direction) {
        case 0: // Up
            snakeY[0] -= 1;
            break;
        case 1: // Right
            snakeX[0] += 1;
            break;
        case 2: // Down
            snakeY[0] += 1;
            break;
        case 3: // Left
            snakeX[0] -= 1;
            break;
    }

    //check if the snake hit the boudary of the window, if yes then game over.
    if (snakeX[0] < 0 || snakeX[0] >= WINDOW_WIDTH / GRID_SIZE || snakeY[0] < 0 || snakeY[0] >= WINDOW_HEIGHT / GRID_SIZE) {
        gameOver=true;
    }

    //check collion between head and body, if yes then game over.
    for (int i = 1; i < snakeLength; ++i) {
        if (snakeX[0] == snakeX[i] && snakeY[0] == snakeY[i]) {
            gameOver=true;
        }
    }

    //check if the snake's head collide with the fruit, if yes the score will increase.
    if (snakeX[0] == fruitX && snakeY[0] == fruitY) {
        score += 1;
        snakeLength++;
        generateFruit();
    }
}


void renderScore(){
    SDL_Color textColor = {255,255,255};
    char scoreText[20];
    sprintf(scoreText, "Score: %d", score);

    SDL_Surface* surface = TTF_RenderText_Solid(font, scoreText, textColor);
    SDL_Texture* texture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer, surface);

    int textWidth = surface->w;
    int textHeight = surface->h;

    SDL_Rect textRect = {10, 10, textWidth, textHeight};
    SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, texture, NULL, &textRect);

    SDL_FreeSurface(surface);
    SDL_DestroyTexture(texture);
}


//render everything, the snake, the fruit, the score
void render() {
    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 0, 0, 0, 255);
    SDL_RenderClear(renderer);

    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 0, 255, 0, 255);
    for (int i = 0; i < snakeLength; ++i) {
        SDL_Rect rect = { snakeX[i] * GRID_SIZE, snakeY[i] * GRID_SIZE, GRID_SIZE, GRID_SIZE };
        SDL_RenderFillRect(renderer, &rect);
    }

    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 255, 0, 0, 255);
    SDL_Rect fruitRect = { fruitX * GRID_SIZE, fruitY * GRID_SIZE, GRID_SIZE, GRID_SIZE };
    SDL_RenderFillRect(renderer, &fruitRect);

    renderScore();

    SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
}


//render the score


//Game over screen
void showGameOver(){
    bool quit=false;
    SDL_Event event;

    while (!quit){
        //render the game over screen 
        SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 255,255,255,255);
        SDL_RenderClear(renderer);

        //render the Game Over text
        SDL_Color textColor = {0, 0, 255};
        SDL_Surface* surface = TTF_RenderText_Solid(font, "Game Over!", textColor);
        SDL_Texture* texture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer, surface);

        int textWidth = surface->w;
        int textHeight = surface->h;

        SDL_Rect textRect = {(WINDOW_WIDTH - WINDOW_HEIGHT) / 2, (WINDOW_HEIGHT - WINDOW_WIDTH) / 2, textWidth, textHeight};
        SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, texture, NULL, &textRect);
        SDL_FreeSurface(surface);
        SDL_DestroyTexture(texture);

        // Render the option in the game over screen
        surface = TTF_RenderText_Solid(font, "Press ESC to quit the game or press R to restart", textColor);
        texture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer, surface);

        textWidth = surface->w;
        textHeight = surface->h;

        SDL_Rect textRect1 = {(WINDOW_WIDTH - WINDOW_HEIGHT) / 2, (WINDOW_HEIGHT - WINDOW_WIDTH) / 2 + 30, textWidth, textHeight};
        SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, texture, NULL, &textRect);

        SDL_FreeSurface(surface);
        SDL_DestroyTexture(texture);
        SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);

        //Handle the input for choosing options in game over screen
        while(SDL_PollEvent(&event)){
            if(event.type == SDL_QUIT){
                quit = true;
                gameOver=true;
            }

            else if(event.type == SDL_KEYDOWN){
                if(event.key.keysym.sym == SDLK_ESCAPE){
                    quit=true;
                    gameOver=true;
                }
            }

            else if (event.key.keysym.sym == SDLK_r){
                quit=true; 
                
            }
        }
    }
}

//everything is here
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    srand(time(NULL));

    //initialize the SDl library and create the game window, if failed,  will exit the program and return to 1 which indicating an error.
    if (!init()) {
        return 1;
    }

    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 0, 0, 0, 255);
    SDL_RenderClear(renderer);
    SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);

    //generate the initial fruit position
    generateFruit();

    //generate the initial position of the snake
    snakeX[0] = WINDOW_WIDTH / (2 * GRID_SIZE);
    snakeY[0] = WINDOW_HEIGHT / (2 * GRID_SIZE);
    //initial length
    snakeLength = 1;
    direction = -1;
    gameOver = false;
    score = 0;

    renderScore();

    //records the current time
    Uint32 lastTime = SDL_GetTicks();

    //loop the game 
    Uint32 currentTime = 0;
    while (!gameOver) {
        currentTime = SDL_GetTicks();
        Uint32 deltaTime = currentTime - lastTime;

        handleInput();

        if (deltaTime >= GAME_SPEED) {
            handleInput();
            moveSnake();
            render();
            lastTime = currentTime;
        } 
    }

    //show the game over screen
    showGameOver();
    //close the SDL resources before exit the program
    close();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are outputting the error message. It says "Library not initialized". You are not calling [TTF_Init](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL2_ttf/TTF_Init) anywhere. Perhaps you should do that.

Comment: Please take some time to read the [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Do not include your error as an image and remove code not related to your problem.

Comment: I suggest that you read this: [Why not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/12149471)

Answer (score 2):

The error `Library not initialized` is because the library is not initialized. Initialize it and check the result.

```
if (TTF_Init() < 0) {
    // Error handling code
}
```

Then you can load the font.

```
TTF_Font* font = TTF_OpenFont("arial.ttf",24);
```